# Why the material UI component cannot get Style value in responsive screen?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want my Paper Style automatically changed when the screen is big or medium or small.

> here what i have imported

```
import React from 'react';
import reactMixin from 'react-mixin';
import ResponsiveMixin from 'react-responsive-mixin';

import Paper from 'material-ui/lib/paper';
```

> i use ResponsiveMixin to determine screen changed

Paper**style={this.state}** where i want to have value changed automatically. **and those value come from componentDidMount()**

```
export class MainLayout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height: '100%',
            paddingTop: 60,
            marginLeft: 258,
            marginRight: 6,
            paddingLeft: '4%',
            paddingRight: '4%'

        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.media({maxWidth: 600}, function () {
            /*small*/
            this.state = {
                height: '100%',
                paddingTop: 60,
                marginLeft: '3%',
                marginRight: '3%',
                paddingLeft: '2%',
                paddingRight: '2%'
            }
        }.bind(this));

        this.media({minWidth: 601, maxWidth: 1024}, function () {
            /*medium*/
            this.state = {
                height: '100%',
                paddingTop: 60,
                marginLeft: '3%',
                marginRight: '3%',
                paddingLeft: '6%',
                paddingRight: '6%'
            }
        }.bind(this));

        this.media({minWidth: 1025}, function () {
            /*large*/
            this.state = {
                height: '100%',
                paddingTop: 60,
                marginLeft: 258,
                marginRight: 6,
                paddingLeft: '4%',
                paddingRight: '4%'
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }

    render() {

        const {header, content, footer} = this.props; // destructure this.props to consts
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    {header}
                </header>
                <main>
                    <Paper style={this.state} zDepth={1}>
                        {content}
                    </Paper>
                </main>
                <footer>
                    {footer}
                </footer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
reactMixin(MainLayout.prototype, ResponsiveMixin);
```

> Your help will greatly appreciated :D Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you store styles in component's state? [Try this](https://gist.github.com/junkycoder/9a37c5076b8d360155d630fdb9afd507)

Comment: I have no idea to get style value to my Paper style :(

Answer (score 0):

The `componentDidMount()` method runs only one time after the component output has been rendered to the DOM according to the documentation. So event if screen size change, nothing will happen. @Material-UI provide a method called [withStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) that helps to wrap styles and provide a `classes` object that containts all styles you defined.  The `withStyles` method automatically update when screen size change. Here is and exemple:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
    paper: {                             // For extra small screens (phones)
        height: '100%',
        paddingTop: 60,
        marginLeft: '3%',
        marginRight: '3%',
        paddingLeft: '2%',
        paddingRight: '2%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {  // For small screens (tablets)
            paddingLeft: '6%',
            paddingRight: '6%'
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {  // For medium screens and above
            marginLeft: 258,
            marginRight: 6,
            paddingLeft: '4%',
            paddingRight: '4%'
        }
    }
})

export class MainLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {header, content, footer, classes} = this.props; // destructure this.props to consts
        return (
            <div>
                <header>
                    {header}
                </header>
                <main>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper} zDepth={1}>
                        {content}
                    </Paper>
                </main>
                <footer>
                    {footer}
                </footer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// That injects `classes` object styles in your component
const YourStyledComponent = withStyles(styles)(MainLayout); 

export default YourStyledComponent; // Export or do what you want with the component
```